# How to connect C# to Snowflake using Dapper?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dapper

I am trying to connect a procedure written in Snowflake database using Dapper.
Everytime I run the code I am getting "**Feature not supported**". While using same stored procedure in ADO.net, it works fine.

Below is the code I am using

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<TestClass>> GetTestData()
{
    IEnumerable<TestClass> response = new List<TestClass>();

    using (IDbConnection dbConnection = this.databaseConnection.GetSnowConnection())
    {
        IEnumerable<TestClass> result = new List<TestClass>();

        try
        {
            result = await dbConnection.QueryAsync<TestClass>("CALL TESTSP1", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, commandTimeout: 0);

            response = response.Concat(result);
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `"CALL TESTSP1", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure,` seems wrong. Either use `"TESTSP1", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure,` or `"CALL TESTSP1"` and default CommandType

Comment: @Charlieface used ```"TESTSP1", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure,``` and still it is not working, giving same error

Comment: And leaving off `commandType` maybe?

Comment: @Charlieface So, ```var result = await dbConnection.QueryAsync<TestClass>("CALL TESTSP1()", commandTimeout: 0);``` this works, now main challenge is to pass the parameters with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems for whatever reason that Snowflake does not support `CommandType.StoredProcedure`. Incidentally, if you were planning on using it then you would leave off the `CALL` part.

Instead just use the default `CommandType.Text`

```cs
result = await dbConnection.QueryAsync<TestClass>("CALL TESTSP1", commandTimeout: 0);
```

Or with parameters (Dapper can infer them from an object)

```
result = await dbConnection.QueryAsync<TestClass>(
    "CALL TESTSP1(:Value1, :Value2)",
    commandTimeout: 0,
    params: new {Value1, Value2}
);
```